# How to manage env with laravel and vue3

Tags: laravel, vuejs3, laravel-8

I have a recently installed vue3 to laravel.
In laravel **.env** I have a

```
MIX_API_URL=http://localhost:8080/api/
```

In vue I have

```
this.apiUrl =  process.env.MIX_API_URL,
```

When I run ***npm run dev*** it all works

But now I need to run ***npm run production*** how do I set up the env for that?
I had env.production but this does not work. I have followed all examples I cannot find but can't find a solution.

Any advice?

Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

**Laravel doesn't use multiple `.env` files. If I'm not mistaken NodeJs has this feature.**

Once you commit the code using GIT and when you pull the code to the server, you won't get the `.env` by default(it's in the git `.gitignore` list). You have to set it up on the server with its configurations.

**The short answer is => set up the `.env` in the server and run the command. It serves from `.env` automatically.**

Comment: Yes, that might be so. However, for Vue, I have to do npm run dev, which compiles the js for local. And when I do npm run production it will use a different env (usually this is the case). with remote api endpoint. There has to be some kind of set up for this. Like env for laravel and a separate env for vue.